# Can I define a function in a parent functional component so that a child PureComponent receiving the function as a prop will not rerender?

Tags: reactjs, react-component, rerender

I have a functional component that renders a collection of simple child components. The parent component has a function that updates state and is passed to the child components. Due to some performance issues, I decided to turn the child components into pure components to reduce the amount of rerenders. Unfortunately, because the function is defined within the parent functional component, the function is being redefined whenever state is updated and the parent is rerendered. This causes the child components to think that the function being passed is a new function and unconditionally causes a rerender.

I already have two separate solutions to this problem, but both are a bit inelegant, in my opinion.

In my first solution, I turned the child components into regular class-based components and defined a custom `shouldComponentUpdate` to basically just ignore the function prop. This is less than ideal since this use-case should really be handled by `PureComponent` or `pure` from the recompose package.

In my second solution, I made the parent component a class-based component and defined the function I wanted to pass down as a prototype method. However, I've been trying to steer clear of class-based components.

This is the class-based code that I would like to recreate as a functional component:

```js
class Parent extends Component {
  state = {
    children: [1, 2, 3, 4] // populated by an api normally
    selectedChildren: []
  };

  handleChildClick = childId => {
    // adds or removes childId from this.state.selectedChildren
    // based on if it's already in the array or not
  };

  render() {
    const children = this.state.children.map((child) => (
      <Child
        key={child}
        id={child}
        onClick={this.handleChildClick}
        selected={this.state.selectedChildren.includes(child)}
      />
    ))

    return (
      <div>
        {children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I would like to know if there is a functional component equivalent of the above code, keeping in mind that the children are pure components that should only rerender if the props passed into them have changed.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there's a hook called [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) that can be used to memoize the function before passing it over to the child component. Since the function has been memoized, the equality comparison will return true if the function is not different. The code in the question would simply be rewritten like this:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [children, setChildren] = useState([1, 2, 3, 4])
  const [selectedChildren, setSelectedChildren] = useState([])

  const handleChildClick = useCallback(
    childId => {
      // adds or removes childId from selectedChildren state
      // based on if it's already in the array or not
    },
    []
  )

  const childComponents = children.map((child) => (
    <Child
      key={child}
      id={child}
      onClick={handleChildClick}
      selected={selectedChildren.includes(child)}
    />
  ))

  return (
    <div>
      {childComponents}
    </div>
  );
}
```